# How do I create a custom weather icon for my site using flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am currently trying to create a custom weather icon for my private website. I have done research for weeks on this but cant seem to find a site that shows how to create\link the XML to the Flash\Actionscript 3.0 script. I am a newbie and have a good concept of how it is to work but can quite get it to load that way I'd want. What I have done so far: Created two  movie clips in flash, one for all 47 weather code (images) and another to display the HIGH, LOW temp as well as the code description for the images. I have attempted to created two XML files for both movie clips. However this is where I seem to get stuck. Below I have included both scripts for my movie clips. They seem to be conflicting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for my text to load from my XML file

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.events.Event;

 var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("feed.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete",fileLoader);

function fileLoader(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

    num1 = xmlData.high;
    num2 = xmlData.low;
    codeid_txt = xmlData.text;
    }


****Here is the code for the icons to load ******

stop();
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

var xmlData2:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("feed.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete",fileLoader);

function fileLoader(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

    icons_mc = xmlData.code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have one icon per frame in the icons_mc, are these frames labeled exactly the same xmlData.code could return?

If that is the case, then you should:

```
icons_mc.gotoAndStop(xmlData.code);
```

Comment: Ahhhh ok l think I named them based on the weather type vs the code number. Let me change that and try this again. I will get back to you to let you know how it worked out. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yeah I am not getting it to work. I am trying to link to Yahoo weather but I am unable to get my XML to work in Flash. I am not 100% sure that I have configured my XML correctly. I thought this would be much easier but apparently not.